# Two databases same server with different time zones

Tags: oracle, timezone

I want to have two databases on same server but want the data in each to reflect the time zone of the client.  Do I need to adjust database parameters or can this be handled with client (JDBC or OCI) settings?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is very open ended and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or [**too broad**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Consider adding more information, e.g. How would the data look like that two clients are entering, what would the data have to look like on retrieval, data or date & time, ....

Comment: Make life easy for yourself - store everything as UTC and let the client handle the conversion. Why anyone would want to do anything else is beyond me!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the same data and have it automatically converted to the timezone of the client, that is just a matter of a session level setting with [TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE Datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169). Example:

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 timestamp with local time zone);

Table created.

SQL> alter session set time_zone = '+02:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select current_timestamp from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-JUN-19 07.05.01.908465 PM +02:00

SQL> insert into t1 values(current_timestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter session set time_zone = '-09:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from t1;

C1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-JUN-19 08.05.11.187305 AM

SQL> insert into t1 values(current_timestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> alter session set time_zone = '+02:00';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from t1;

C1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03-JUN-19 07.05.11.187305 PM
03-JUN-19 07.05.36.714308 PM

SQL>
```

If you really want to store both the timestamp and the timezone offset, then you can use [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081).